# Endomorphism of a local $k$-algebra inducing an automorphism modulo $m^2$ is an automorphism

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals, deformation-theory, finitely-generated

The following is exercise 4.1 of Hartshorne's *Deformation Theory*, used in the proof given there of the sufficiency of the infinitesimal lifting criterion of smoothness:

> Let $(A,m)$ be a local $k$-algebra with residue field $k = A/m$. Let $f : A \rightarrow A$ be a $k$-algebra homomorphism inducing an isomorphism $A/m^2 \rightarrow A/m^2$. Show that $f$ is itself an isomorphism.

Certainly there needs to be a finiteness hypothesis, so far I only need $m$ is finitely generated, but I'm willing to even assume Noetherian.

I can show it is surjective: Let $x_1, \dots, x_n$ be generators of $m$, then we get a surjective map $m/m^2 \rightarrow m/m^2$ and so $\langle f(x_1), \dots, f(x_n)\rangle$ generate (by abuse of notation) $m/m^2$ as a $k$-module. Then 
  $$m = m^2 + \langle f(x_1), \dots, f(x_n) \rangle$$
and so by Nakayama's lemma we get that $f$ surjects onto $m$ and hence all of $A$.

---

Edit: At the request below, I will show that $f : m \rightarrow m$ is surjective implies $f : A \rightarrow A$ is surjective. It suffices to show that for any unit $u \in A$, there exists an element of $A$ which maps onto $u$. Consider $\bar{u} \in A/m = k$. Since $k \rightarrow A \rightarrow A/m$ is an isomorphism, there exists $\lambda' \in A$ that maps onto $\bar{u}$. Then $u = f(\lambda') + b$ for some $b \in m$. Letting $f(a) = b$, we have $f(\lambda' + a) = u$ as required.

---

For injectivity, we certainly have $\mathrm{ker} f \subset m^2$. But how does one show that it is zero? Perhaps we can use Nakayama again: it suffices to show that $m \cdot \mathrm{ker} f = \mathrm{ker} f$ but I haven't been able to make this work.

I feel all but certain I'm missing something easy.

Comment: Why is it true that $f(x_i) \in m$?

Comment: @Manos: Great question! Although the problem doesn't specify it, I believe $f$ is assumed to be a local homomorphism.

Comment: @Manos: on second thought, doesn't this follow from the map $R/m^2 \rightarrow R/m^2$ being an isomorphism? If $a \in m$ was sent to a unit, then this unit would be sent to $a$ under the inverse.

Comment: Ok, i see what you mean.

Comment: @rghthndsd Why if $f$ is onto from $m$ to $m$ then it is onto from $A$ to $A$?

Comment: @user121097: I've edited my question.

Comment: @rghthndsd The only way I can understand "$u=\lambda+b$ for some $b\in m$" is that you assume the identity from $A/m$ to $A/m$ factorizes through $A$, that is, $k=A/m\to A\to A/m$ is the identity, where the first morphism makes $A$ a $k$-algebra and the second is the canonical projection. Why this?

Comment: @user121097: When one says that the residue field of a $k$-algebra is $k$, it means that the composition $k \rightarrow R \rightarrow R/m$ is an isomorphism. So my proof was admittedly a little sloppy, but (IMO) ok. I'll fix the abuse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A surjective endomorphism of a noetherian ring is an automorphism.

Take $f:A\to A$ a surjective endomorphism and the ascending chain of ideals $\ker f\subseteq\ker f^2\subseteq\cdots$. Then there exists $n\ge 1$ such that $\ker f^n=\ker f^{n+1}=\cdots$. Replace $f$ by $f^n$ and assume that $\ker f=\ker f^2$. Now take $a\in\ker f$. Since $f$ is surjective $a=f(b)$ and from $f(a)=0$ we get $f^2(b)=0$, so $b\in\ker f$, that is, $f(b)=0$ and we are done.